# Wrong Tab Selected after Calling preventDefault() using ui-router and md-tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router, preventdefault

I am attempting to move from using angular's built-in router with md-tabs to ui-router and found a nice [pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WVsbSHfplx82FXywYq2G?p=info) that demonstrates how easily it can be configured to work.

Now, if the user attempts to tab away from a dirty page, I'd like to raise a dialog that allows cancellation of the move. So I added this code to the app's run() method:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        console.log(' fromState: '+fromState.name +'; toState: '+toState.name);

            if (confirm("Would you like to change state?")){
              console.log('going to: '+toState.name);
            } else {
              console.log('staying at state: '+fromState.name);
              event.preventDefault();
            }

      });
```

If I select tab2 and cancel the state change in the dialog, the tab1 text remains displayed, as desired. However, tab2 becomes the actively-selected tab.

I found some suggestions about calling `$state.go(fromState.name)` after `preventDefault()` but that doesn't solve the problem.

[This page](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/14/deep-linking-a-tabbed-ui-with-angularjs.aspx) describes similar behavior with deep tabbing and proposes a workaround but I wasn't able to see how to apply it to my code example (which, by the way, also demonstates the same problem upon deep tabbing: going directly to state tabs/tab2 displays the tab2 content but again tab1 is the active tab.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I did have the same issue. Seems to work for me using 'ng-click' directive with '$state.go' instead of 'ui-sref'. Then you need to stop click event propagation and manage active state using 'md-active' directive.

Then your markup looks like:

```
<md-tabs md-align-tabs="top">

<md-tab md-active="$state.includes('tabs.tab1')">
  <md-tab-label>
    <span ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();$state.go('tabs.tab1')">Tab 1</span>
  </md-tab-label>
</md-tab>

<md-tab md-active="$state.includes('tabs.tab2')">
  <md-tab-label>
    <span ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();$state.go('tabs.tab2')">Tab 2</span>
  </md-tab-label>
</md-tab>
```

Check it here : http://plnkr.co/edit/O2y8Rn1SmuquXTjucrgm

Comment: almost nailed it. but clicking on the edges of the tab it still lets you switch without even asking.

Comment: then you have to change the styles to be sure than the span takes all the space within the tab.

.md-tab-item {
    padding:0;
}

md-tab-item span {
    padding: 0 24px;
    line-height: 48px;
    display: block;
}

Comment: Alternatively, you can just move `padding: 12px 24px;` from `md-tab-item` to `md-tab-item span`.